# Create Regular Expression to Match Custom Format

Tags: objective-c, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression that matches when the string starts with 1 or more alpha characters followed by exactly 1 `?` and ending with 1 or more alpha characters

What I have so far is

```
[A-Za-z]+\?{1}[A-Za-z]+
```

but this is causing my program to crash. Any ideas? Thanks for any responses.

**UPDATED**

Here is the exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
'Can't do regex matching, reason: (Can't open pattern U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX 
(string fe?ing, pattern [A-Za-z]+?{1}[A-Za-z]+, case 0, canon 0))'
```

Seems to be ignoring the escape character for the ?

Comment: What's the symptoms of the crash, and please post more of the code that's calling it. The regex looks OK (although you don't need the {1} as just putting \? means match the literal ?). Have you tried with simpler regexs to check it's not the calling code that's at fault?

Comment: if I replace the ? with a 1 then the regex works fine. It'll match strings like fas1ing correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That does look right.  Maybe take off the "{1}" but it works with Perl expressions when I try it.

Try doing this:  if you put the "?" into a character class to see if you can break out of the crash.

```
[A-Za-z]+[?][A-Za-z]+
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use 2 backslashes.

```
@"[A-Za-z]+\\?[A-Za-z]+"
```

One backslash to escape the `\` for the compiler as a string literal, another one to escape the `?` for the regex engine.